# Is `dispatch_source_cancel(timer)` sufficient to cancel recurring task?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a recurring task I want to run in my ios swift.
below is my code to repeat a task.

How can i stop the re-fresh task?

Am i missing something in the `stopRefreshTimer()`

Even if i don't miss anything, can it be that an old scheduled task will run even after I called `stopRefreshTimer()` ? Or is the halt immediate.

```
   func startRefreshTimer() {
        if (timer != nil)  {return }

        let queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.domain.app.timer", nil)
        timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue)
        dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 5 * NSEC_PER_SEC, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC) // every 60 seconds, with leeway of 1 second
        dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer) {
            if (self.timer == nil) {return}
            self.getLineState(self.lineName)

        }
        dispatch_resume(timer)
    }

    func stopRefreshTimer() {
        if (timer != nil)
        {
            dispatch_source_cancel(timer)
            timer = nil
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A `DispatchSource` works like this: It monitors the system for certain events, and as soon as such an event is detected, it schedules the callback of the handler on its target queue.

With a timer source, the system clock is monitored until it reaches a certain value; as soon as this value is reached, the handler is scheduled. Therefore, the timer source calculates at which value of the system clock it should be triggered (or triggered again, if repeating timer) and asks the kernel scheduler to tell it when this value is exceeded.

The moment you call `cancel` on a source, it will no longer look for events. So if you cancel a timer source before the next fire time has been reached, the handler will certainly never be scheduled again.

However, there is a race condition. If the event has already been triggered, the source has already scheduled the handler for execution in the queue, which does not happen immediately. If you now cancel the source, no more handler callbacks will be scheduled, but the one callback that has already been scheduled will continue to be executed as GCD does not support canceling a scheduled dispatch block.

Think of

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // ... do something ...
}
```

this block is not executing immediately but it will for sure be executed after being scheduled like that, there is no way to cancel its execution.

Let me translate your Swift code to modern Swift syntax:

```
func startRefreshTimer( )
{
    guard self.timer == nil else { return }

    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.domain.app.timer")
    let timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: queue)
    timer.setEventHandler {
        [weak self] in
        if let self = self {
            self.getLineState(self.lineName)
        }
    }
    timer.activate()
    self.timer = timer
}


func stopRefreshTimer( )
{
    self.timer?.cancel()
    self.timer = nil
}
```

One important change is that the handler block only captures a weak reference to `self`, otherwise you get a retain cycle, as `self` keeps the timer alive and the timer keeps `self` alive, so they keep each other alive forever, even if nobody has any reference to that object anymore.

Being a weak reference, you first have to turn it into a strong reference before using it, that's what the `if let self = self` does. It will either turn `self` into a strong reference and execute the if-content or it won't, in which case the object was deallocated between scheduling the callback and executing the callback. The alternative would be something like:

```
self?.getLineState(self?.lineName)
```

or if the argument to `getLineState` must not be `nil`

```
self?.getLineState(self?.lineName ?? <fallback>)
```

To fix the race condition, three changes are required. The first change is to verify the timer is still alive (you original code already did that):

```
if let self = self, self.timer != nil {
    self.getLineState(self.lineName)
}
```

But that alone won't fix it. Keep in mind, that the handler is always executed on the target queue of the timer, whereas `stopRefreshTimer()` is executed on any thread/queue. So you must keep a reference to the queue to be able to schedule code to run on that specific queue:

```
timer.activate()
self.timer = timer
self.timerQueue = queue // <---
```

And then you must ensure that your stop call is also performed on that queue, otherwise your code is not even thread-safe:

```
func stopRefreshTimer( )
{
    self.timerQueue.async {
        self.timer?.cancel()
        self.timer = nil
    }
}
```

Now the code is at least thread-safe, as the timer is for sure canceled and set `nil` on the same queue that executes the handlers. But as the dispatch is async, you cannot know for sure if there was still a handler scheduled prior to your stop call, so if you need to know for sure that no handler callback is never executed after calling stop, you must use a sync dispatch:

```
self.timerQueue.sync {
    self.timer?.cancel()
    self.timer = nil
}
```

Now once the function call returns, this block has been executed and it has been executed on the timer queue, meaning no further handler callbacks are ever scheduled on that queue for sure and there also cannot be any pending callbacks that were no yet executed as if there were pending ones, they would have to be executed prior to that sync block. Once the stop call returns, all previously scheduled callbacks already did finish executing and all later scheduled ones wouldn't do anything as `timer` is now `nil`.

Note however that sync-dispatching means that if you try to call `stopRefreshTimer()` from within code that is already running on the `timerQueue`, you create a deadlock and your app will freeze, as the code won't continue, until the scheduled block has been executed, yet the scheduled block cannot ever execute, as you are blocking the queue that is supposed to execute it. So sync-dispatching has to be used with a lot of care. Async-dispatching is always safe, but it also means that just because the function has returned does not mean that the timer has already been canceled yet.